# fetch method for sending json not working

Tags: python, ajax, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I made a web-app using flask and SQLAlchemy. I don't understand why I cannot view a response on my fetch request. Every time my catch method gets called and shows error message.

**Here is my html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Todo app</title>
        <style>
            .hidden {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form">
            <input type="text" id="description" name="description" />
            <input type="submit" value="create"/>
        </form>
        <div id="error" class="hidden">Something went wrong!</div>
        <ul id="todos">
            <li>check</li>
            {% for d in data %}
            <li>{{ d.description }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                fetch('/todos/create', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        'description': document.getElementById('description').value
                    }),
                    headers: {'Content=Type': 'application/json'}
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function(jsonResponse) {
                    console.log(jsonResponse);
                    const liItem = document.createElement('LI');
                    liItem.innerHTML = jsonResponse['description'];
                    document.getElementById('todos').appendChild(liItem);
                    document.getElementById('error').className = 'hidden';
                })
                .catch(function() {
                    document.getElementById('error').className = '';
                })
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here is my python app**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://postgres:asdf1234@localhost:5432/todoapp'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'todos'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Todo {sefl.id} {self.desc}>'
db.create_all()

@app.route('/todos/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_todo():
    description = request.get_json()['description']
    todo = Todo(description=description)
    db.session.add(todo)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({
        'description': todo.description
    }) 

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', data=Todo.query.all())
```

I am getting this message in terminal where I am running my python app when I give some input in the view:

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2020 20:19:58] "GET /?description=foo HTTP/1.1" 200 -

I think this means request is successful?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.

What have you tried so far and what are the errors you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your header values, you have written `Content=Type` not `Content-Type` inside fetch

Answer (score 0):

If after making the corrections to the headers and still doesn't work, try refreshing the page after clicking the create button